# R lapply need to use a different input depending on which value is being evaluated

Tags: r, lapply

Say I have a list c of three data frames:

```
> c
$first
           a          b
1          1          2
2          2          3
3          3          4

$second
           a          b
1          2          4
2          4          6
3          6          8

$third
           a          b
1          3          6
2          6          9
3          9         12
```

I want to run an lapply on c that will do a custom function on each data frame.
The custom function depends on three numbers and I want the function to use a different number depending on which data frame it's evaluating.

I was thinking of utilizing the names 'first', 'second', and 'third', but I'm unsure how to get those names once they're inside the lapply function. It would look something like this:

```
lapply(c, function(list, num1 = 1, num2 = -1, num3 = 0) {num <- ifelse(names(list) == "first", num1, ifelse(names(list) == "second", num2, num3)); return(list*num)})
```

So the result I would want would be first multiplied by 1, second multiplied by -1, and third multiplied by 0.

The names function gives the values a and b (the column names) instead of the name of the data frame itself, so that doesn't work. Is there a function that would be able to give me the 'first', 'second', and 'third' values I need?

Or alternatively, is there a better way of doing this in a lapply function?

Answer (score 1):

May be, it would be easier with `Map`.  We pass the number of interest in the order we want and do a simple multiplication

```
Map(`*`, lst1,  c(1, -1, 0))
```

If the numbers are named

```
num1 <- setNames(c(1, -1, 0), c("first", "third", "second"))
```

then, match with the `names` of the `list`

```
Map(`*`, lst1,  num1[names(lst1)])
#$first
#  a b
#1 1 2
#2 2 3
#3 3 4

#$second
#  a b
#1 0 0
#2 0 0
#3 0 0

#$third
#   a   b
#1 -3  -6
#2 -6  -9
#3 -9 -12
```

---

Or if we decide to go with `lapply`, loop over the `names` of the `list` , extract the `list` element based on the name as well as the corresponding `vector` element (`named` vector)

```
lapply(names(lst1), function(nm) lst1[[nm]] * num1[nm])
```

Or with `sapply`

```
sapply(names(lst1), function(nm) lst1[[nm]] * num1[nm], simplify = FALSE)
```

---

Or another option is `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map2(lst1, num1[names(lst1)], `*`)
```

---

Note: `c` is a function name and it is not recommended to create object names with function names

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(first = structure(list(a = 1:3, b = 2:4), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3")), second = structure(list(a = c(2L, 4L, 6L), b = c(4L, 
6L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3")), 
    third = structure(list(a = c(3L, 6L, 9L), b = c(6L, 9L, 12L
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3")))
```

Comment: Thank you! I used your idea with the lapply and using the names as the first input. I tried using Mapply, and it worked with the simple example, but when I tried applying it to the more complicated situation, it was returning some strange results.

Comment: @AnthonyH  Not sure about your complicated example.  This is based on the example you showed in your  post

Comment: Don't worry about it. The lapply method worked great!

Answer (score 0):

Besides the solutions by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59618255/12158757'), you can also try the following code

```
mapply(`*`, lst1,  c(1, -1, 0),SIMPLIFY = F)
```

or

```
lapply(seq_along(lst1), function(k) lst1[[k]]*c(1,-1,0)[k])
```